# HWUT choice order

Tags: c, unit-testing, hwut

I am using choices in my `HWUT` test.

- If in the command line, I don't specify the choice, then the test runs for all the choices.
- And the test is run for each choice as per alphabetical order. But, I would the like the test to run the choices based on the order specified in the test file, as specified below.

For example:

```
printf("CHOICES: start, do_something, end");
```

I would like to it execute in the same order.

I did see some information regarding ordering of choices in this [page](http://hwut.sourceforge.net/html/deterministic/interview.html).

This mentions about FIRST, NOT_LAST, NOT_FIRST, LAST. I couldn't figure out how to use this.  Also, I'm not sure if this is the solution.

Comment: Why would you want to be able to choose an order such as 'end', 'start, 'do_something'?  Is choices really the appropriate option to be using?  Are you sure you shouldn't just be doing serial testing?  Or do you have some sort of 'begin', followed by any sequence of 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', finishing up with 'end' — or some other fancy scheme like that?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Ok, maybe start and end are not relevent here. In my case i have test 1, test2, test3, etc. For test2 to run test1 should have completed. test2 should be run before test3 etc.  I could make test1, test2, test3 as different tests, but is it possible to run the tests in same folder in a particular order? Even that seems to run based on alphabetical order.

Comment: I've not used HWUT, so I don't know about it and can't really help more.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A HWUT Test's choice relates to a test that is completely independent. Your **setup procedure** must create a deterministic environment and the results  **must not depend on external things** and **must not depend on the history** of HWUT tests!
2. If you have such a history dependency, then you must code the tests in a single choice (or, not having any choices at all).
3. Sometimes you 'make/build' things that are useful for all tests. For example, you might generate a huge database that is used by all CHOICES. When the last test finishes, the huge database shall be remove from the file system. Then, it makes sense to consider FIRST and LAST.

So, let us assume your case is case 3. Then, you check whether it is the first and/or last CHOICE by checking on argv[2] and argv[3] as described in the page that you reference.

```
/* Begin of 'main()' */
if( argc > 2 && strmp(argv[2], "FIRST") == 0 ) {
   /* Build some stuff to be used by all CHOICES. */
}

... test current CHOICE ...

/* End of 'main()' */
if( argc > 3 && strmp(argv[3], "LAST") == 0 ) { 
   /* Delete some stuff that has been used by all CHOICES. */
}
```

Comment: Hi Frank, thanks. As per your second point, if i make test1, test2, test3 as independant tests with single choice, is there a way to run the tests in the order i need. Becuase if i have test files in a partcular folder, the tests executables run as per alphabetical order.

Comment: i understand that the environment must be deterministic. But if i have to start my test at the same point and test the different flows, the amount of data that will be collected will be too high. That is the reason i want to end the test once a particular path is tested. Then move on from there to test other paths. so this requires the HWUT to run the tests in a particular order, whether it is using choice or not.

Answer (score 0):

If 'start' 'do_something', and 'end' must be executed in that order, then create three functions 'test_start(...)', 'test_do_something(...)', and 'test_end(...)' which execute your tests -- as suggested in item 2.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ...
    test_start(...);
    test_do_something(...);
    test_end(...);
}
```

If something happens in 'start', 'do_domething', and 'end' that can be tested, 
but testing all at once is too much for you, then

```
#include "hwut_unit.h"

int print_index = 0;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ...
    hwut_if_choice("start")        print_index = 0;
    hwut_if_choice("do_something") print_index = 1;
    hwut_if_choice("end")          print_index = 2;
    ...
}
```

And in the 'test_start(...)' function do

```
void test_start(...)
{
    ...
    if( print_index == 0 ) {
        printf(...);
    }
}
```

That is, make your print statements dependent on a 'print_index'.
The 'print_index' in turn must be set according to the CHOICE.